# How do I structure a GWT project?

Tags: java, gwt, module

I have followed the basic GWT tutorial for creating a project in Eclipse.  Now, I am trying to build off what I learned in the tutorial.  I created a static utility class to perform some database connection logic.  However, when I try to compile I get:

```
[ERROR] Line 46: No source code is available for type com.sample.server.ConnectionUtil; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Where can I put simple classes that I've created on my own?  Do they have to be outside the package structure of the basic module, 'com.sample'?  Or do I have to specify a whole new module in the gwt.xml file and inherit from that?  There has to be something simple I'm missing.

Comment: Is ur gwt.xml file within com.sample package?

Comment: Are you using the Google Eclipse Plugin? It should set up correctly everything for you.

Comment: I am actually.  But when I try to create a simple class the plugin didn't generate, I get the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Required reading: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html. That is, you should really really read it after reading this answer.

Check your module file – it has the extension `.gwt.xml`. You'll see a tag called `entry-point`. Any code that you add to your project that you want to run on the **client** side should be in that package or a subpackage.

For example, my entry point is `com.wesley.heapunderflow.client.HeapUnderflow`. All my *translatable* code should be in `com.wesley.heapunderflow.client` or a subpackage.

If you really need to add another package, add a `<source path="package"/>` declaration, where package is something like `com.wesley.heapunderflow.tools` or `com.wesley.skynet`.